# Error during initialization of UserControl within a Class

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Class "DataLib.cs" and an UserControl "MediumTile.xaml". If I use the UserControl within the DataLib.cs by this code:

```
var TestTile = new MediumTile();
TestTile.Measure(new Size(336, 336));
TestTile.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 336, 336));
```

I get this error:

"An exception (first chance) of the type "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException 'occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll."

with markup of this line withing the "MediumTile.g.cs":

```
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/DataLib;component/MediumTile.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

Seem like there is something wrong within the InitializeComponent(); and the directory "component" doesn't exist actually.

MediumTile.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataLib.MediumTile"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="336" d:DesignWidth="336">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="336" Height="336" Background="#FFFF5588">
    <Path x:Name="ico_Cloud" Width="180 " Height="110" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 67.8062,198.672C 30.3579,198.672 4.57764e-005,168.314 4.57764e-005,130.866C 4.57764e-005,93.4175 30.3579,63.0596 67.8062,63.0596L 71.932,63.0596C 85.0272,26.3081 120.131,0 161.379,0C 202.627,0 237.73,26.3081 250.826,63.0596L 256.307,63.0596C 292.4,63.0596 322.757,93.4175 322.757,130.866C 322.757,168.314 292.399,198.672 254.951,198.672L 67.8062,198.672 Z "/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="testTXT" Text=""/>
</Grid>
```

MediumTile.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace DataLib
{
public partial class MediumTile : UserControl
{
    public MediumTile()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TileAktualisieren();
    }

    public async void TileAktualisieren()
    {
        List<String> DatenPacket = await DataLib.Daten();
        string Ort = DatenPacket[0].ToString();
        string Temp = DatenPacket[1].ToString();
        string Code = DatenPacket[2].ToString();

        testTXT.Text = Ort;
    }
}
}
```

Daten() within DataLib.cs:

```
public async static Task<List<String>> Daten()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile DatenDateien = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        string Ort = String.Empty;
        string Temp = String.Empty;
        string Code = String.Empty;


            // Http Request
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Berlin&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string DatenURL = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            RootObject apiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(DatenURL);

            // Write Data into isoStorage
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex())
            {
                mutex.WaitOne();
                try
                {                                        
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream WritingStream4 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Ort.txt", FileMode.Create, DatenDateien);
                    StreamWriter writer4 = new StreamWriter(WritingStream4);
                    writer4.Write(apiData.data.request[0].query);
                    writer4.Close();

                    IsolatedStorageFileStream WritingStream5 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Temp.txt", FileMode.Create, DatenDateien);
                    StreamWriter writer5 = new StreamWriter(WritingStream5);
                    writer5.Write(apiData.data.current_condition[0].temp_C);
                    writer5.Close();

                    IsolatedStorageFileStream WritingStream6 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Code.txt", FileMode.Create, DatenDateien);
                    StreamWriter writer6 = new StreamWriter(WritingStream6);
                    writer6.Write(apiData.data.current_condition[0].weatherCode);
                    writer6.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }              

            }
        }

        // Read Data from isoStorage
        using (Mutex mutex0 = new Mutex())
        {
            mutex0.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream ReadingStream4 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Ort.txt", FileMode.Open, DatenDateien);
                StreamReader reader4 = new StreamReader(ReadingStream4);
                Ort = reader4.ReadToEnd();
                reader4.Close();

                IsolatedStorageFileStream ReadingStream5 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Temp.txt", FileMode.Open, DatenDateien);
                StreamReader reader5 = new StreamReader(ReadingStream5);
                Temp = reader5.ReadToEnd();
                reader5.Close();

                IsolatedStorageFileStream ReadingStream6 = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Code.txt", FileMode.Open, DatenDateien);
                StreamReader reader6 = new StreamReader(ReadingStream6);
                Code = reader6.ReadToEnd();
                reader6.Close();

                // here is the part with the UserControl
                var TestTile = new MediumTile();
                TestTile.Measure(new Size(336, 336));
                TestTile.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 336, 336));

                using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!store.DirectoryExists("shared/shellcontent"))
                    {
                        store.CreateDirectory("shared/shellcontent");
                    }  
                    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(336, 336);
                    bitmap.Render(TestTile, new TranslateTransform());
                    var stream = store.CreateFile("/shared/shellcontent/test.jpg");
                    bitmap.Invalidate();
                    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, 366, 336, 0, 100);
                    stream.Close();
                }

                // Tile
                ShellTile PinnedTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
                FlipTileData UpdatedTileData = new FlipTileData
                {
                    Title = Temp + "°c",
                    BackTitle = Ort,
                    BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/shared/shellcontent/test.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                };
                PinnedTile.Update(UpdatedTileData);

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex0.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }

        return new List<String> { Ort, Temp, Code };
    }
}
```

Comment: You have error in MediumTile.xaml. Can you post layout from this file here ?

Comment: The `component` you mentioned is not for a folder name,it is a part of the pack URI. [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Referenced_Assembly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="336" Height="336" Background="#FFFF5588">
    <Path x:Name="ico_Cloud" Width="180" Height="110" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Data="F1 M 67.8062,198.672C 30.3579,198.672 4.57764e-005,168.314 4.57764e-005,130.866C 4.57764e-005,93.4175 30.3579,63.0596 67.8062,63.0596L 71.932,63.0596C 85.0272,26.3081 120.131,0 161.379,0C 202.627,0 237.73,26.3081 250.826,63.0596L 256.307,63.0596C 292.4,63.0596 322.757,93.4175 322.757,130.866C 322.757,168.314 292.399,198.672 254.951,198.672L 67.8062,198.672 Z "/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="testTXT" Text=""/>
</Grid>
```

You have a `space` after 180 in your Path's width.

Comment: I have found the problem but do not understand why. It's within the MediumTile.xaml.cs - if I remove `TileAktualisieren()` it works but I need to change the content of the UserControl before I use it withn DataLib.cs

Comment: @user3168511 The problem with "180 " was that the System couldn't create System.Double from it. As for TileAktualisieren() the error must be in DatenPacket = await DataLib.Daten(); - can you show the code of Daten()?

Comment: I have added it - but its a lot of stuff ... could the problem be that the data have to go from DataLib.cs to MediumTile.xaml to generate the content for the tile and than have this tile as UserControl to "go back" to DataLib.cs to be generated as image? Thank you for your help - I learn c# since 1 month and have problems to understand this objective part with passing data and so on

Comment: @user3168511 Yeah - quite a lot of code. But there is one bad thing I see for sure - look in your MediumTile you use Daten(), and in this method you have a line: var TestTile = new MediumTile(); - which creates next MediumTile, which invokes Daten(), which creates next and so on - you get StackOverflow. Try to comment that out, debug step by step and try to find other errors (if there are any). You can then also try putting more try-catch blocks for testing.

Comment: Yes I had that feeling of StackOverflow - I have solved that problem now by using the data from isoStorage to generate the UserControl Tile before creating the image.